# How to evaluate a value in List<Map<String, Object>> and compare it to another List<Map<String, Object>>?

Tags: java, list

If I have 2 `List`s of type `Map`:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
List<Map<String, Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

How can I compare the 2 lists through one of the map fields and create a third list with the data from `list2` that is not in `list1`

Example:

```
Map<String, Object> mapA = new HashMap<String, Object>();

mapA.put("cod", 1);
mapA.put("des", "primer");
list1.add(mapA)

mapA.put("cod", 2);
mapA.put("des", "segund");
list1.add(mapA)

Map<String, Object> mapB = new HashMap<String, Object>();

mapB.put("cod", 1);
mapB.put("des", "terce");
list2.add(mapB)

mapB.put("cod", 4);
mapB.put("des", "cuart");
list2.add(mapB)
```

Answer:

```
listNew = {("cod", 4), ("des", "cuart")}
```

I've experimented with contains but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: don't see _any_ effort of solving the problem yourself - what _exact_ did you try and how didn't it work out? Please edit the question and add your code for tackling the task (best as [mcve] to exclude typing errors as seem to have happened here). As-is, it smells like a homework dump ..

Answer (score 0):

So this solution just iterative over the `second list` get every map keyset and then loop over the `first list` and get every map from there and search if there is the same values. If so boolean `contains` become true.

At the end of the loop of the first map check if `contains` is true or false. If false add to the result. Please pay attention that like this only result from the `second list` which are not part of the `first list` will be added to the result.

Also pay attention that in the question example use only one specific value of the key `"cod"` is used for checks between the maps. I updated my answer accepting that only this keys is important for the comparison

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = List.of(Map.of("cod", 1, "des", "primer"), Map.of("cod", 2, "des", "segund"));
        List<Map<String, Object>> list2 = List.of(Map.of("cod", 1, "des", "terce"), Map.of("cod", 4, "des", "cuart"));


        // check them
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map<String, Object> map2 : list2)
        {
            // if you want to check on all keys
            // Set<String> keys = map2.keySet();

            // if you want to check on Specific key for example cod
            Set<String> keys = Set.of("cod");

            for(String key : keys)
            {
                boolean contains = false;
                for(Map<String, Object> map1 : list1)
                {
                    Object v = map2.get(key);
                    if(v != null && v.equals(map1.get(key)))
                    {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(contains == false)
                {
                    result.add(map2);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: tbh. from the question, I have no idea what is the rule to create final list. You use: `if(v != null && v.equals(map2.get(key)))` but we have all elements with same key `("cod", "des")`. Any final list has only 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your "map" contains a code and a description, hence I think you just need a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) and not a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of `Map`s where the map "key" is the value of *cod* and the map "value" is the value of "des".

```java
Map<Integer, String> mapA = Map.of(1, "first", 2, "second");
Map<Integer, String> mapB = Map.of(1, "third", 4, "fourth");
```

Now you want all the "keys" in `mapB` that are not in `mapA`.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> mapA = Map.of(1, "first", 2, "second");
        Map<Integer, String> mapB = Map.of(1, "third", 4, "fourth");
        List<Integer> mapAkeys = mapA.keySet()
                                     .stream()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> mapBkeys = mapB.keySet()
                                     .stream()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
        mapBkeys.removeAll(mapAkeys);
        mapBkeys.forEach(k -> System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", k, mapB.get(k)));
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
4 = fourth
```

Note this part of the code in your question:

```java
Map<String, Object> mapA = new HashMap<String, Object>();

mapA.put("cod", 1);
mapA.put("des", "primer");
list1.add(mapA)

mapA.put("cod", 2);
mapA.put("des", "segund");
list1.add(mapA);
```

`list1` now contains the exact, same `Map` twice and that `Map` contains only two entries, namely:

```
cod = 2
des = segund
```

This is because each "key" can only appear once in a `Map`. In other words, none of the "maps" in `list1` contains an entry where the value for "cod" is 1 (one). If you want a `List` of `Map`s then you need to create a new `Map` for every `List` element, i.e.

```java
List.of(Map.of("cod", 1, "des", "primer"), Map.of("cod", 2, "des", "segund"));
```

Hence my proposed solution that uses a single `Map` rather than a `List<Map>`.
However, if you really require a `List<Map>`, consider the following code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = List.of(Map.of("code", 1, "description", "first"),
                                                  Map.of("code", 2, "description", "second"));
        List<Map<String, Object>> list2 = List.of(Map.of("code", 1, "description", "third"),
                                                  Map.of("code", 4, "description", "fourth"));
        List<Object> list1codes = list1.stream()
                                       .map(m -> m.get("code"))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Values of [[Map] key] \"code\" in entries of 'list1': " + list1codes);
        List<Object> list2codes = list2.stream()
                                       .map(m -> m.get("code"))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Values of [[Map] key] \"code\" in entries of 'list2': " + list2codes);
        list2codes.removeAll(list1codes);
        System.out.println("Values of [[Map] key] \"code\" only in 'list2': " + list2codes);
        List<Map<String, Object>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object search : list2codes) {
            for (Map<String, Object> elem : list2) {
                if (elem.get("code").equals(search)) {
                    list3.add(elem);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list3);
    }
}
```

Running this code displays the following:

```
Values of [[Map] key] "code" in entries of 'list1': [1, 2]
Values of [[Map] key] "code" in entries of 'list2': [1, 4]
Values of [[Map] key] "code" only in 'list2': [4]
[{description=fourth, code=4}]
```